# Share single index for multiple linearly correlated columns

Tags: postgresql, index

I've got a table with two columns whose values have a perfect linear correlation, for example

```
CREATE TABLE measurements (
  sensor int PRIMARY KEY,
  num serial PRIMARY KEY,
  time timestamptz DEFAULT now(),
  value float
);
-- many times:
INSERT INTO measurements(sensor, value) VALUES ($1, $2);
```

Both the `time` and the `num` are monotonously increasing, a row with higher `num` value will also have a larger `time` value.

Postgres will create a btree index on the primary key columns. Can I somehow tell it to also **use the same index** when querying for rows by their `time` instead of by their `num`? As in

```
SELECT * FROM measurements WHERE sensor = $1 AND time >= $2 ORDER BY time;
```

The resulting rows would have exactly the same order as if sorted by `num`.

Is there a way to let the optimiser know? I've seen many articles on cross column correlation statistics, most of them linked in [this StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25812345/1048572), but the [multi-column statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html) seems to only analyze dependencies between individual values, and are unable to do a [linear correlation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-STATISTICS-TABLE).

I was hoping to achieve the same result as if I created another index on `sensor, time`, but have postgres need to maintain and store only a single index.

Comment: why not change the primary key to be (sensor,time) instead ?  timestamptz is internally the same as bigint so will only be slightly less efficient than serial in the index,

Comment: @Jasen I'm kinda afraid that the timestamp is not unique enough. What is the resolution of the clock used for `now()`? Instead of a (big)serial my actual code uses `txid_current()` as part of the primary key, to prevent duplicate insertions by a single transaction - maybe my example is not really good. I made this question primarily to learn about indices.

Comment: one microsecond  (or one millisecond on win-32 last time I  looked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use an index on one column for searches on another column. I second Jasens comment that you should consider doing away with the generated integer and using the timestamp instead.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I wanted to know. I guess the example was choosen a bit unfortunate. Maybe a better showcase for the problem would be if each measurement consisted of a series of data points that are known to be monotonically increasing, i.e. the index within the measurement and the value are correlated.